# Transitive set ordered by epsilon

Tags: set-theory

This problem is from [here](http://www.princeton.edu/~jburgess/PHI323S13Problems.pdf)

> **Definition)** A set t is called transitive if every element of every element of t is itself an  element of t, or equivalently, if every
>   element of t is a subset of t. A set t is said to be  ordered by
>   epsilon if for any two elements x and y of t, either x ∈ y or x = y or
>   y ∈ x
>
> **5.**  Let x and y be transitive sets, each ordered by epsilon.
>
> (a) Show using foundation that if y - x ≠ Ø, then x ∩ y ∈ y. [Hint:
>   Let z be an epsilon-minimal element of y - x, and show z = x ∩ y.]
>
> (b) Show that either x ∈ y or x = y or y ∈ x. [Hint: A proof like that
>   of (a) shows also that if x - y ≠ Ø, then x ∩ y ∈ x]
>
> Can there be two distinct sets each of exactly four elements, each
>   both transitive and  ordered by epsilon?

I'm solving (a), and I found out that $z\subseteq x \cap y$. (Let $w$ be an element of $z$, then since $z \in y$ implies $z \subseteq y$, $w$ is an element of $y$. If $w$ is not in $x$, then $w \in z \cap (y-x)$, a contradiction. Hence $w \in x$ and $z\subseteq x$, consequently $z \subseteq x \cap y$.)

But I don't know how to show that $z=x \cap y$. Is the problem okay? If I take $x$ to be empty set, then the conclusion is $\emptyset \in y$, which seems to be false.

**Edit** Thanks to hints, I solved (a),(b) and also I think that a set of exactly four elements, both transitive and ordered by epsilon is unique: Obviously $4=\{ 0,1,2,3 \}$ is one. Let $y$ be another one. If $4\in y$, then $0,1,2,3,4 \in y$, a contradiction. If $y \in 4$, then $y$ is one of $0,1,2,3$ which do not have 4 elements, a contradiction.

Also I found that every (nonempty) transitive set has the empty set: If $x$ is a nonempty transitive set, then $y \cap x = \emptyset$ for some $y\in x$. If $z\in y$, then $z \in x$, a contradiction. Hence the $\in $-minimal element of $x$ should be the empty set.

Then my question: Every transitive set ordered by epsilon is an ordinal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** (for (a)) We must show that every element $w$ of $x \cap y$ is an element of $z$.  Show that the assumptions $w = z$ and $z \in w$ both lead to contradictions, and then use the fact that $y$ is ordered by $\in$.

**Hint:** (for (b)) If $x \neq y$, then without loss of generality we may assume $y \setminus x \neq \emptyset$.  Applying (a) we have that $x \cap y \in y$. So it suffices to show that $x \cap y = x$.  Note that $x \cap y$ is transitive and ordered in $\in$.  If $x \cap y \neq x$ use (a) to show that $x \cap y \in x$.  A contradiction (to Foundation) is now staring at you.

Comment: I got it. $w=z$ or $z \in w$ both lead to $z \in (x \cap y)\cap(y-x)=\emptyset$.

Comment: But can you give me any hints for (b), last question? I'm having trouble in them, too.

Comment: @Gobi: An outline for (b) has been added.  Your contradictions for (a) seem fine.

Answer (score 5):

How do you define an ordinal? Often the ordinals are defined as transitive sets which are well-ordered by $\in$, these are known as the von Neumann ordinals.

However $\in$ is well-founded, so well-ordered by $\in$ is equivalent to being [linearly] ordered by $\in$.

So yes, every transitive set which is ordered by $\in$ is a von Neumann ordinal, and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks, I should study more about ordinals.

Comment: But it is prudent to remark that foundation is essential for this equivalence. For example, there are models of the other $\mathsf{ZFC}$ axioms, where foundation fails, and there are sets $x$ that satisfy $x=\{x\}$. These sets are transitive and linearly ordered by $\in$, but are not ordinals.