# Who is Epsilon ($\epsilon$)? a binary relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, ordinals

I was reading:

[Transitive set ordered by epsilon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366268/transitive-set-ordered-by-epsilon)

and

http://www.princeton.edu/~jburgess/PHI323S13Problems.pdf (ex. 4)

so, who is epsilon?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's the name of a Greek letter: $\epsilon$. It's not a person's name. Notice that the E is not capitalized.

Comment: @Soviet the correct term is "what", not "who" is epsilon.

Comment: Ah, so you meant to say "What", not "who". In set theory, it usually means "in": For example, $ x \in \mathbb{N} $ means $x$ is in the set of naturals. And as I am typing this, I've been beaten by three people in a matter of seconds! :P

Comment: According to Erdos, Epsilon is any possible child.

Comment: Yes, but we're talking to StackExchange users, not users familiar with Erdos (unfortunately).

Comment: @MathApprentice How can you make some an assumption? Don't take me wrong, but your comment sounded a bit arrogant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Epsilon* is the name of $\epsilon$, the fifth letter of the Greek alphabet; here it refers to the *membership relation* $\in$, as when we write, for instance, $3\in\Bbb Z$. When we say that a set $S$ is *ordered by epsilon*, we mean that $\langle S,\in\rangle$ is a strict linear order: if $x,y\in S$, then exactly one of $x\in y$, $x=y$, and $y\in x$ holds. This is analogous to $\langle\Bbb N,<\rangle$ being a strict linear order: for each $m,n\in\Bbb N$, then exactly one of $m<n$, $m=n$, and $n<m$ holds.

Comment: so we have a relation in $A$, with $A$ transitive set?

Comment: thanks soo much... thanks!! :)

Comment: @Soviet: Yes: to say that $A$ is a transitive set is to say that $\in$ is a transitive relation on $A$. You’re welcome!

Comment: M.Scott.. the relation epsilon is defined only if $S$ is a transitive set?

Comment: @Soviet: No, $\in$ is defined on every set. A *transitive* set is one on which it is transitive.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "espilon" the authors might have written "the is-an-element-of relation", but that doesn't sound cool.

Comment: Historically the symbol **was** in fact $\varepsilon$ and $\epsilon$. Hence the name.